# How to remove Web Essentials from Chrome after disabling browser link

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I have set "enable browser link menu" to false the Web Essentials options in Visual Studio, however, I still see this error message in Chrome console.

```
[09:21:58 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)] Browser Link: Exception thrown when trying to invoke Browser Link extension callback "madskristensen.editorextensions.browserlink.unusedcss.unusedcssextensionfactory.GetIgnoreList":
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BrowserLink.UnusedCss.UnusedCssExtension.GetIgnoreList()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.ClientMessaging.DispatchMessage(BrowserLinkConnection connection, MessageArgs obj)
```

This is my only gripe after disabling browser link is seeing this message in my console nearly everytime I open the Developer Tools on the console log view.

I have tried finding the extension (`chrome://extensions/`) or plugin (`chrome://plugins/`) but it is not listed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the issue raised with Web Essentials
https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/550

The solution is to disable Visual Studio's browser link.

I could only do this via the toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply Go to Tools >> Extensions and Updates
2. Look at the installed programs.
3. Disable Web Essentials 2013, 5 Update

> > Voila !! Your problem is solved